# problem predicting a value in R using a regression model

Tags: r

I need to predict the R&D expenses for a company with 5000 employees. I already created the linear regression model as follows:

```
lrmodel_2 <- lm(Data1_3$RD~Data1_3$employees, data = Data1_3)
summary(lrmodel_2)
```

I then used the `predict` function to predict expenses for 5000 employees. However when I try to predict I get a table with multiple values instead of 1:

[(predict function result image)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NEyPg.png)

Any help would be very much appreciated.

Comment: change model creation to `... lm(RD~employees....` . Predict data should be a data frame, create it like this: `pred_emp <- data.frame(employees = 5000)`. Does it solve the problem?

Comment: I tried that but it did not fix it

Comment: No one can run your code except you because the input is missing. Please read the information at the top of the [tag:r] tag page on how to ask a question.